# Как сделать карточку автора

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Здраствуйте, мне нужно создать карточку автора типо слева обложка книги, а справа по очереди сверху вниз:
Автор:
Название:
Рейтинг:
Оценка:
Отзыв:

И внизу под этим всем Описание:

И что бы это было обёрнуто в border(книга отдельно, и каждый из пунктов по отдельности) у меня так получилось[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #add8e6;
  font-size: 26px;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.solid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background: #add8e6;
  position: absolute;
  top: -160px;
  transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.solid:hover {
  top: 0;
}

.solid p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 39px;
  word-spacing: 46px;
}

.solid a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.content-color {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

.book {
  border: 5px solid #1087af;
  width: 65%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 45px;
}

.book-text {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
  /*padding-left: 3px;*/
  border-bottom: 10px solid #1087af;
}

.strelki {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.next-page {
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.next-page1 {
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-left: 95%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.previous-page {
  margin-top: 0%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Book Reviews Mirokioo</title>
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="solid">
    <p><a href="index.html">Главная </a><a href="#">Топ2 </a><a href="#">Топ1 </a><a href="#">Бонус</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-color">
      <h2>ТОП 3</h2>
      <div class="book">
        <p><img src="assets/image/Картинка 1.png" alt="" style="padding: 0%; margin: 0%; width: 220px; height: 300px; border-right:5px solid #1087af; border-radius: 14px; align-items: flex-end;"><span class="book-text">Автор: Даниель Киз</span><span class="book-text">Название: <small>Цветы для Элджернона</small></span>
          <span
            class="book-text">Рейтинг: <b>18+</b></span><span class="book-text"></span><span class="book-text"></span><span class="book-text"></span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="strelki">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/image/strelka2.png" alt="" class="previous-page"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/image/strelka1.png" alt="" class="next-page"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Может бы вы показали картинку, чего вы хотите?

Comment: Я хочу что бы картинка книги была слева(а по её правой стороне была линия), так же хочу что бы были отделы типо Автор: и внизу линия ну и т.д., а под всем этим Описание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
p{margin: 0;} /*сжимаем <p> */
#x{
display: grid;
/* выбираем грид модель(способ и набор правил для размещения
элементов на странице), она одна из самых понятных и удобных */

grid-template-columns: 1fr/* ширина первого столбца - обложки */
1fr/*ширина второго с текстом*/;
/* 1fr - единицы использующиеся только в грид модели */

grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto);
/*количество и высота строк */

grid-auto-flow: dense;
/* это на всякий случай, чтоб пунты с текстом не
"всплывали над картинкой" но похоже и без него норм*/

grid-gap: 1em; /* дополнительное расстояние между
элементами(картинкой и пунктами с текстом) */
}

#x > img{
background: pink;
grid-row: 1 /span 6;
/*растягиваем картинку "от 1й строки до 6й" */
}

#x, #x > *{ /* это селекторы. "#x" - тег с id='x'
"#x > *" - все теги находящиеся внутри него(тега с id='x') */
padding: .2em;
border: 3px solid skyblue;
border-radius: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id='x'>
<img alt='цветы для элджерона'>
<p>Автор: Даниель Киз</p>
<p>название: Цветы для Элджернона</p>
<p>рейтинг: 18+</p>
<p>Оценка: 10/10</p>
<!--Тут звезды как иконки будут под цифрами-->
<p>Отзыв: Книга просто класс прочитал в захлёб всем советую!</p>
<p id="opisanie">Описание: блаблабла скукотища не ну реально!</p>
</div>
```

сойдет?

Comment: Практически (да многого я ещё не знаю в HTML CSS) можно что бы расстояние между словами сверху и снизу было меньше... Хотя да даже очень я думаю если немного (мне) заморочится то я смогу  изменить так как надо. И можно ли статью или типо того ч о бы понять что вы написали? Если тэги я могу загуглить то что это "#x" и "#x>#x" ну и типо того, я же не просто ответ хочу знать, а возможно ещё и научиться..

Comment: "#x" "#x > #x", почитайте про [CSS Селекторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Спасибо и по поводу того как должно выглядеть вот HTML: <div id='x'>
            <img alt='цветы для элджерона'>
            <div class="punkt">
                <p>Автор: Даниель Киз</p>
            <p>Название: <small> Цвиты для Элджернона</small></p>
            <p>Рейтинг: <b>18+</b></p>
            <p>Оценка: 10/10</p><!--Тут звезды как иконки будут под цифрами-->
            <p>Отзыв: Книга просто класс прочитал в захлёб всем советую!</p>
            </div>
            <p id="opisanie">Описание: блаблабла скукотища не ну реально!</p>
       </div>

Comment: CSS:#x{
margin:0%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-auto-flow: dense;
border-radius: .5em;
height:235px;
width:330px;
border:5px solid skyblue;
grid-gap: -2em;
}

#x > img{
background: pink;
grid-row: 1 /span 4;
height:235px;
width:150px;
border-right:5px solid skyblue;
}

#x p{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:-10px;
    word-spacing:;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:5px solid skyblue;
}

Comment: Но мне надо ещё что бы это "Описание" было под всем этим тоже имело border (но только слева, справа и снизу), и было на всей длине этой карточки и она будет готова! Практически останутся ещё звёздочки в виде оценки, но это уже мелочи. Если можно помогите.

Comment: У меня получилось, я выставил описание за div x, сделал border с права с лева и снизу, и сделал margin-top -5, теперь осталось сделать что бы текст не прилегал к верхней части

Comment: @Krenic дополнил до состояния примитивной шпаргалки, но если что то не понятно спрашивайте :3

Comment: @puffleeck Как текст "Описание :" открепить от верхней границы, но и так что бы border был в притык к основной части карточки? Просто я пытался теми знаниями что имею это сделать но не получается. Помогите ещё с этим и я думаю на этом все...

Comment: У меня получилось все карточка готова, ну если не учитывать что закругленые углы border выперают а так все очень хорошо и замечательно, спасибо!